# Window scrolls without triggering touchmove

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on this AngualarJS app on a touch device and there is a place where I am disabling scrolling through attaching a handler on `touchmove`. However, I have tested the device and can verify that a touchmove is not necesarrily triggered when the screen scrolls - only touchstart and touchend could just be triggered as well. The trick is to "tap a bit hard on the screen fast with a very slight upward drag motion".

How else could I disable scrolling? Note: I cannot e.preventDefault the touchstart event, as I need it for something else while the scrolling is disabled. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my viewport, disabled scroll have many ways:

1. `e.preventDefault()` but this one you don't allow
2. use CSS

how to make one place begin scroll? there are two doms: `scroll-wrapper` & `scroll-area`

1. `scroll-area` size bigger than `scroll-wrapper`
2. `scroll-wrapper` has `overflow: scroll`

So, stop area scroll:

1. they have the same size
2. `overflow: hidden` (`touchmove` listener change the CSS position can imitate scroll)

Now, you wanna disable the scroll of one area.Maybe you could just use CSS to do this.

Hope I can help you.